# Extracting a URL using a regular expression

Tags: regex, vba, excel, outlook

I receive 10 or 12 emails from the same website and I would like to extract a particular URL using regex (if possible) and have it pasted into the correct Excel file. The e-mails are in Outlook and I already have a VBA script (that runs from Outlook VBA) that I used to extract the Subject and Sender. However, I really need that particular URL in each e-mail to be the third piece of information extracted.

I have tried to create a series of steps to:

1. create the RegEx
2. apply the RegEx to the current email
3. place the extracted URL into the excel document.

However, whatever I have created fails miserably. The VBA pasted below always worked until I wrote in the additional RegEx part.

I believe I have the correct pattern:

```
/http:\/\/www.changedetection.com\/log(.*)/ig
```

Whenever I run the new VBA script, it doesn't do anything. The old code always worked. The code is written into This Outlook Session (just to clarify) because the mailitem needs to run from a script.

```
Const xlUp As Long = -4162
Sub ExportToExcel(MyMail As MailItem)

    Dim strID As String, olNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim Reg1 As RegExp
    Dim M1 As MatchCollection
    Dim M As Match

    Set Reg1 = New RegExp
    With Reg1
        .Pattern = "http://www\.changedetection\.com/log(.*)"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Global = True
     End With

    If Reg1.test(olMail.Body) Then

        Set M1 = Reg1.Execute(olMail.Body)
        For Each M In M1
        strBody = M.SubMatches(1)
        Next
    End If

    '~~> Excel Variables
    Dim oXLApp As Object, oXLwb As Object, oXLws As Object
    Dim lRow As Long

    strID = MyMail.EntryID
    Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)



    '~~> Establish an EXCEL application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '~~> If not found then create new instance
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Set oXLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0

    '~~> Show Excel
    oXLApp.Visible = True

    '~~> Open the relevant file
    Set oXLwb = oXLApp.Workbooks.Open("M:\Monitor\Monitor_Test_1.xlsx")

    '~~> Set the relevant output sheet. Change as applicable
    Set oXLws = oXLwb.Sheets("Test")

    lRow = oXLws.Range("A" & oXLApp.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    '~~> Write to outlook
    With oXLws
        '
        '~~> Code here to output data from email to Excel File
        '~~> For example
        '
        .Range("A" & lRow).Value = olMail.Subject
        .Range("B" & lRow).Value = olMail.SenderName
        .Range("C" & lRow).Value = strBody

        '
    End With

    '~~> Close and Clean up Excel
    oXLwb.Close (True)
    oXLApp.Quit

    Set Reg1 = Nothing
    Set oXLws = Nothing
    Set oXLwb = Nothing
    Set oXLApp = Nothing

    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olNS = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

VBScript regex patterns don't use `/` to indicate the start and end. Nor do they use `i` or `g` after the trailing `/` to indicate case-insensitivety or globalness. Instead, use the `IgnoreCase` and `Global` properties.

For example:

```
With Reg1
    .Pattern = "http://www\.changedetection\.com/log(.*)"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
End With
```

[Here's a great reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx) if you're looking for more information about the `RegExp` object.

Comment: Thank you bond for your help. I inserted the correction into my script. It still doesn't work. I run the script and...nothing. I must have something else screwed up. I will read the reference you sent me. If you have any other suggestions I would like to hear them.

Comment: Is it not branching into your `If Reg1.test(olMail.Body) Then` statement?

Comment: Yes. I believe you are correct. It is not branching at all.

Comment: Try the regex above. You shouldn't need to escape forward slashes but you do need to escape dots.